# Dynamic Content Controls with embedded XML to the .docm file

Tags: xml, vba, ms-word

How can you dynamically populate a drop-down content control from an embedded XML within the (.docm) file. I know that you can appended the (.zip) file extension to an office document and create a custom UI as an add-in; I would like to use the same concept and insert a XML file that holds a list of items and populate that list into a drop-down content control inside a word document when the word document is opened.

Answer (score 1):

MS Word tends to silently remove everything it cannot understand. So I'm pretty sure it will remove your file from document file. And it's not even considering thet you want to access a file, already opened in Word. So I think it is really bad idea. If you want to store some hidden info in your file - there is only one legit way - [customXMLParts](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff861714.aspx).

And considering [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3168353/word-2007-vba-activedocument-customxmlparts-and-drop-down-lists) answer, I think customXMLParts exist exatly for your purpose.

Comment: @AlexButendo: I read through the website; but where would I insert/embed the custom XML file?

Comment: you can use part of the macros provided there, or you can prepare it using OpenXML. I don't know how to do it without code.